# Should I use TNSNAMES.ORA or tnsnames.ora?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to connect to Oracle from OS X. I have this file here:

```
/usr/local/oracle/network/admin/TNSNAMES.ORA
```

Online I've seen references to this file with the filename in both upper and lower case. Which is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official documentation has it in lowercase: [Local Naming Parameters (tnsnames.ora)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/tnsnames.htm), so I'd go with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are under default HPFS (non-case sensitive) it does not matter.

I would prefer "tnsnames.ora". But that's just a matter of taste.